# PHP GET variable `/` instead of  `?`

Tags: php, variables, get

I'm working with a script that doesn't allow `$_GET[]` variables in the URL (it's a referrer url I'm giving out and I need to have some way to track it). I can't have this for example `domain.com/index.php?id=test`. However i can do this `domain.com/index.php/idd=test`

My question is if i use `/` instead of `?` and treat it like a get variable. How do i get the variable from the url. What's an easy way to do this

Comment: Look up the [mod_rewrite](http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/) method.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is use POST instead of GET? Second thought is using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and doing some creative parsing? -- edit -- or if you can use mod_rewrite, then what @BradChristie suggested.

Comment: I don't think $_POST is a viable option. what if he means something like somedomain.com/index/category/id

Comment: I need to use get. It's a referrer url i'm giving out and i need to have some way to track it. Post will not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php/whatever
```

Then the `/whatever` is commonly known as [`PATH_INFO`](http://www.google.com/search?q=PATH_INFO) and available as:

```
print $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]
```

Note that some environments (CGI) can have it set to placeholder values (request_uri) when an actual path_info wasn't present. (See also PHP manual on the environment variables http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php and the notes about PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED.)

```
.htaccess: php_value arg_separator.input &;/
# Else strtr(..., "/", "&")

parse_str($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"], $_GET);
```

Should populate $_GET.

Comment: I'm kinda embarrassed that I didn't know about `PATH_INFO`. Bravo

Comment: Learned something new. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "easy" way to replace the entire functionality of $_GET parameters, but there are some awkward hacks, at least under Apache. Given that you cannot use $_GET parameters, I'll assume you don't have access to mod_rewrite either, but who knows.

A request like `http://www.example.com/index.php/foo/bar/baz`
will generate the following items in the $_SERVER superglobal:

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /index.php/foo/bar/baz
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[PATH_INFO] => /foo/bar/baz
```

In theory, you can then parse $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] by splitting on "/", looping through that array and splitting on "=" (assuming you're still going to use a key=value structure).

Be aware, however, that a side effect of the wonky URL structure is that relative links in your document will become relative to the wonky URL, so an image like

`<img src="images/myimage.jpg">`

will attempt to load `http://www.example.com/index.php/foo/bar/images/myimage.jpg`

This can be avoided by using absolute URLs (`http://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg`) or root-relative URLs (`/images/myimage.jpg`).

But basically, you're asking for a world of trouble...and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$segments = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

then you decide from there. each one of the results from $segments can be manipulated the same way. You can choose to do id=test or just the id and always know that $segments[2] is id, for example. Your call.

You should definitely look into mod_rewrite though. you need to redirect calls to a file cause this method will not allow anything past .php if you are not allowed get vars. (assuming through some config ? and beyond is not read)

basically reroute everything to index.php if that's your one controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse it like this:

```
$uriParts = array_reverse((array) explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$GET = explode('=', $uriParts[0]); // however you wanted to parse it form here
```

Do with it as you wish, just know that `$uriParts[0]` would contain `id=whatever`.

Comment: Do i have to check if `=`  exists in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` so i know there is a variable to work with

Comment: I would imagine it's up to you since you would be providing the referral link, right?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then do what you need to it.

from your example you need something like this:

```
//get rid of "/index.php
$uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 11);
//explode incase there are other parameters
$arr = explode('&', $uri);
$token = array();
foreach($token as $t){
    $part = explode('=', $t);
    $token[$part[0]] = $part[1]
}
```